# JavaScript: Filter Array of Shoe Objects for Specific Type of Shoes and Return Object Array with Index as Property

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, indexing

I have the following array of shoe objects:

```
var currentInventory = [
  {
    name: 'Brunello Cucinelli',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'tasselled black low-top lace-up', price: 1000},
      {name: 'tasselled green low-top lace-up', price: 1100},
      {name: 'plain beige suede moccasin', price: 950},
      {name: 'plain olive suede moccasin', price: 1050}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Gucci',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'red leather laced sneakers', price: 800},
      {name: 'black leather laced sneakers', price: 900}
    ]
  }
];
```

Using the currentInventory array above, I want to find all the laced shoes and indicate which word contains lace:

Desired output below:

```
[
  {
    "nameWords": [
      "tasselled",
      "black",
      "low-top",
      "lace-up"
    ],
    "targetWordIndex": 3
  },
  {
    "nameWords": [
      "tasselled",
      "green",
      "low-top",
      "lace-up"
    ],
    "targetWordIndex": 3
  },
  {
    "nameWords": [
      "red",
      "leather",
      "laced",
      "sneakers"
    ],
    "targetWordIndex": 2
  },
  {
    "nameWords": [
      "black",
      "leather",
      "laced",
      "sneakers"
    ],
    "targetWordIndex": 2
  }
]
```

Below is my attempted code; it comes close but not quite there:

```
function renderLacedShoes(inventory) {

  //console.log(inventory)

  let finalArr = []; 


  for (let i=0; i<inventory.length; i++){
    let indObj = inventory[i];

    let newObj = {};

    // dive into values associated with shoes 

    for (let k=0; k<indObj.shoes.length; k++){
      let shoeNameArr = indObj.shoes[k].name.split(" ");    

      //console.log(shoeNameArr)

      if ( (shoeNameArr.includes('lace-up')) || (shoeNameArr.includes('laced')) ){

        newObj['nameWords'] = shoeNameArr;
        console.log(newObj)

        // not working below
        newObj['targetWordIndex'] = (shoeNameArr.indexOf('lace-up' || 'laced'))
      }
    }
    finalArr.push(newObj);
  }
  return finalArr;
}


// TEST: 
renderLacedShoes(currentInventory)
```

My code outputs:

```
[ { nameWords: [ 'tasselled', 'green', 'low-top', 'lace-up' ],
    targetWordIndex: 3 },
  { nameWords: [ 'black', 'leather', 'laced', 'sneakers' ],
    targetWordIndex: -1 } ]
```

I see two issues: It's not returning ALL the "lace" containing shoes.  Also, my targetWordIndex is off.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Quick test shows your `indexOf` call doesn't work with the `||` operator. It seems to only check the first string, and returns -1 if it doesn't find it.

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.findIndex()` instead. And you stated you only need to look for `"lace"` within those words...so see if the actual strings include it

Answer (score 1):

You have not only a problem with the index, but also with the pushing the result. This should take place inside of the inner loop.

```js
function renderLacedShoes(inventory) {
    let finalArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
        let indObj = inventory[i];
        for (let k = 0; k < indObj.shoes.length; k++) {
            let nameWords = indObj.shoes[k].name.split(" ");
            let targetWordIndex = nameWords.findIndex(s => s === 'lace-up' || s === 'laced');
            if (targetWordIndex !== -1) {
                finalArr.push({ nameWords, targetWordIndex });
            }
        }
    }
    return finalArr;
}

var currentInventory = [{ name: 'Brunello Cucinelli', shoes: [{ name: 'tasselled black low-top lace-up', price: 1000 }, { name: 'tasselled green low-top lace-up', price: 1100 }, { name: 'plain beige suede moccasin', price: 950 }, { name: 'plain olive suede moccasin', price: 1050 }] }, { name: 'Gucci', shoes: [{ name: 'red leather laced sneakers', price: 800 }, { name: 'black leather laced sneakers', price: 900 }] }],
    result = renderLacedShoes(currentInventory);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let renderLacedShoes = (arr) => {
    const array = [];
    arr.forEach(elem => {
        elem.shoes.forEach(names => {
            let nameWords = names.name.split(" ");
            nameWords.forEach((elem, i) => {
                if (elem.indexOf("lace") >= 0) {
                    array.push({
                        nameWords: nameWords,
                        targetWordIndex: i
                    });
                }
            });

        });
    });
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt it using a chain of `map` and `filter` to reach to desired solution

```js
var res = [{ name: 'Brunello Cucinelli', shoes: [{ name: 'tasselled black low-top lace-up', price: 1000 }, { name: 'tasselled green low-top lace-up', price: 1100 }, { name: 'plain beige suede moccasin', price: 950 }, { name: 'plain olive suede moccasin', price: 1050 }] }, { name: 'Gucci', shoes: [{ name: 'red leather laced sneakers', price: 800 }, { name: 'black leather laced sneakers', price: 900 }] }]
 .map(d => d.shoes.map(r => r.name)).flat()
 .filter(d => d.includes('lace'))
 .map(d => ({ nameWords: d.split(' '),  targetWordIndex: d.split(' ').findIndex(d => d.includes('lace'))}))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: thank you for this!  I have been trying to practice more problems using array methods like filter, map, reduce .... do you have a site with lots of good practice problems?

Comment: You can start with official Mozilla docs, picking one topic at a time say "higher order functions" and then refer some e-books/sites for deeper understanding. One of the good ones is : https://eloquentjavascript.net/

Comment: By the way for practicing how I approached was, I picked smartest JS people from Stackoverflow, one of them being Nina, and saw questions they answered, I attempted that myself first and then compared with their attempt. This helps ALOT to quickly see what approach one must take to attempt problem :)